# Randomize values within a DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, random, merge

I have a dataframe (df) and a variable containing a group number. Each observation has a group number going from 1 to 80. I would like to create a new variable, called new_group, containing new random numbers from 1 to 80 for each observation. However, these new group numbers must be consistent with the original group numbers in the sense that if 2 observations were in group 1, both observation should have the same new random group number.

Example:

```
observation    group   random_group
0                1         4
1                2         3
2                1         4
3                43        1
4                1         4
5                21        80
6                43        1
```

I am using Python 3.7. I tried the following:
1.I created a dictionary with keys from 1 to 80 and values from 1 to 80 but with a different, random order. The idea is to use this dictionary to do a Excel "vlookup" type of matching.

2. I created a new dataframe with 2 columns: one colum with values from 1 to 80, and another column with numbers with 1 to 80 but in a different, random order. The idea would be to merge the original dataframe with the new one.

Here is what I did:

```
import random
ordered_group = list(range(1,81))
random_group = random.sample(range(1, 81), 80)
group_dict = dict(zip(ordered_group ,random_group))

df['new_group'] = df.group.map(group_dict)
```

The new_group column only has nan

I also tried this instead of the last line:

```
df['new_group'] = df["group"].apply(lambda x: group_dict .get(x))
```

Now it maps correctly all 80 groups once but it does not go through all observations

I also tried using `merge` instead of using `map`

```
import random
random_group= list(range(1,81))
random_group= pd.DataFrame(random_group)
random_group['new_group'] = random.sample(range(1, 81), 80)
random_group.rename(columns={0:'group'},inplace=True )


df= df.merge(random_group, on = 'group', how = 'outer')
```

It maps correctly all 80 groups once but it does not go through all observations

So i get something like this:

```
observation    group   random_group
0                1         4
1                2         3
2                1         nan
3                43        1
4                1         nan
5                21        80
6                43        nan
```

My two methods seem to work well but they do not go through the whole dataframe. Any idea where did I go wrong? Also, any more efficient method is welcome

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the random mapping in a `dict` then `map`. In this case the random group ranges from 1-4 because you only have 4 unique groups. In your real data this would go from 1-80 if you have 80 groups.

```
import numpy as np

grps = df.group.unique()
N = df.group.nunique()

d = dict(zip(np.random.choice(grps, N, replace=False), range(1, N+1)))
#{1: 3, 2: 2, 21: 4, 43: 1}

df['random_group'] = df['group'].map(d)
#   observation  group  random_group
#0            0      1             3
#1            1      2             2
#2            2      1             3
#3            3     43             1
#4            4      1             3
#5            5     21             4
#6            6     43             1
```

Comment: Worked brilliantly, thanks! But i can't seem to understand why my dictionary and use of map resulted in nan.

Comment: @JulienSalé It's unclear to me too. You should look at the output of `df.group.unique()`. My guess is that you could be having an issue with strings and integers. So perhaps you have both `1` and `'1'` representations in your column. I think you should convert the column to `int`, then I think your original method would work. Mine works because it uses the real values of `group`, but also check what `N` is in the above. If you have multiple `str` and `int` representations of the same group then `N` is going to be`> 80` and the mapping might not work as you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

What i did was generate random group each time and check if original group was already assigned in a new group or not.
This seems to work for me :

```
import pandas as pd
import random
data=pd.read_csv('file.csv')
processed_group=[]
for obs in data['observation']:
   x = int(random.randrange(1,80))
   if data.loc[obs,'group'] not in processed_group:
       data.loc[obs,'new_group']=x
       processed_group.append(data.loc[obs,'group'])
   elif data.loc[obs,'group'] in processed_group:
       index = data.index[data['group']== data.loc[obs,'group']].tolist()
       data.loc[obs,'new_group'] = data.loc[index[0],'new_group']
```